# Selenium tests hang on CI while loading content

Tags: selenium, jenkins, timeout, webdriver

I'm trying to debug some Selenium tests but I cannot reproduce the issue locally. On the CI, after selecting some check boxes, the page reloads (a loading animation is displayed), and on the Jenkins agent it hangs for hours. I tried using these options, which I've added in the class constructor of the page:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(8, SECONDS);  
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(8, SECONDS);
```

Also I tried

```
public static void waitForLoadingPopUpToBecomeInvisible() {
        try {
            WebdriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            wait.until(invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("loading")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            driver.navigate().refresh()
        }
    }
```

I want to refresh the page if the loading animation is visible for more than X seconds, or to force kill the test if it has been running for more than Y minutes.

Can you please suggest any better ideas?

Comment: Just a question, could you share your integration code of CI and Selenium? I want to know, How are you integrating your script with CI tool?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that script...

Comment: I want to know, How are you integrating your script with CI tool?

Because I also faced same problem with CruiseControlDotNet CI tool and when I was changed the integration script it works fine.

Comment: Jenkins is using a script to pull the changes from Git. It is configured as a build step for the defined job. For the first build of this job, I did a git clone from the project repository, but now it's jut pulling the latest changes.